# Can DISTINCT lambda functions work on PARALLEL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can DISTINCT lambda functions work on PARALLEL?

If yes then kindly send me a java example, I have searched a lot online but unfortunately I have found only things related to running same lambda functions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to expand on your question more, specifically what are you expecting Lambda to do for you? Do you have Java code that better illustrates your needs, or a link to a document that describes what you're looking to achieve at a high level?

Comment: Are you asking whether multiple (separate) invocations of Lambda can run in parallel, or are you asking whether a single Lambda function can run parallel threads? (Actually, the answer to both is Yes.) Please provide more details about what you are trying to do (code samples encouraged), and what difficulties you are experiencing.

Comment: I am currently trying to use aws lambda functions to represent multiple services to monitor their QoS over time. So my question is it possible to run different aws lambda functions in parallel ? Hope that now its clearer.